# How to retrieve POST body data in ApiController?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net 4.5 and latest MVC version. I need retrive `deviceId` and `body` from header when posting the form in the html page. At line `public void Post([FromBody]string value)` value it is always null.

Wha am I doing wrong here?

```
  namespace WebApi.Controllers
    {
        public class NotificationController : ApiController
        {
            // GET api/notification
            public IEnumerable<string> Get()
            {
                return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
            }

            // GET api/notification/5
            public string Get(int id)
            {
                return "value";
            }

            // POST api/notification
            public void Post([FromBody]string value)
            {
// value it is always null
            }

            // PUT api/notification/5
            public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
            {
            }

            // DELETE api/notification/5
            public void Delete(int id)
            {
            }
        }
    }


<form action="/api/notification" method="post">
    DeviceId: <input name="deviceId" value="gateeMachine">
    Body: <input name="body" value="Warning Out of Paper">
    <button>Tes send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model binder matches the parameters to the values from the name attributes in your form.  I find it's less of a headache to create models though (the following is untested code):

```
public class Devices
{
     public string DeviceId { get; set; }
     public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

The Action:

```
public void Post(Devices device)
{

}
```

The form:

```
<form action="/api/notification" method="post">
    Device Id: <input name="DeviceId" value="gateeMachine">
    Body: <input name="Body" value="Warning Out of Paper">
    <button>Test send</button>
</form>
```

-- EDIT: It turns out that binding multiple form values isn't supported (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407458/webapi-multiple-put-post-parameters) answer), so the model is the way to go.  You could serialize your form values into the querystring.  You could also serialize the values into a single string (i.e. JSON or XML) and then deserialize server-side, but really, the model is the most straight forward path here.

Comment: using first approach wihtout model i get Can't bind multiple parameters ('deviceId' and 'body') to the request's content... any idea?

Comment: do you have an idea why ([FromBody]string deviceId, [FromBody]string body) does not work?

Answer (score 0):

well your post is accepting one parameter 'value' and you are trying to send it two parameters 'deviceId' and 'body'.  Fixing that would be a good place to start.