# Access to web API from a console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, console

In the process of learning about web API, I have created (or actually Visual Studio has) a simple controller. I have also created a WPF program that can read from web API's GET() part, but I can't access the others.

I have tried a lot and found many blogs and pages that say: "Just do like this..." but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

MVC part:

```
namespace MVCWebservice.Controllers
{
    public class LaLaController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/LaLa
        public string Get()
        {
            return "Hello from API";
        }

        // GET: api/LaLa/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST: api/LaLa
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            var a = value;
        }

        // PUT: api/LaLa/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
            var b = value;
            int c = id;
        }

        // DELETE: api/LaLa/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            int c = id;
        }
    }
}
```

And a method from my Console application that actually works:

```
private static async Task ReadFromWebApi()
{
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:26176/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var resp2 = await client.GetAsync("api/LaLa/");
    resp2.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var aaa = resp2.Content;
    string result = await aaa.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

A method that just stops:

If I remove the `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` I'll get the following back:

> ss = "{\"Message\":\"The requested resource does not support http
>   method 'PUT'.\"}"

```
private static async Task SendToWebApi()
{
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:26176/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    Console.WriteLine("-1-");
    var resp2 = client.PutAsync("api/LaLa/", new System.Net.Http.StringContent("Hey", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
    Console.WriteLine("-2-");
    resp2.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var ss = await resp2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

How would I write my access to the other methods?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you are calling PUT on the URL `api/LaLa/`, but from the server's method signature

```
public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
```

it appears that the URL should include a numeric id to satisfy the first parameter, e.g. `api/LaLa/100` or similar. Perhaps you could modify your client to call `PutAsync()` like this:

```
var resp2 = client.PutAsync("api/LaLa/100", new System.Net.Http.StringContent("Hey", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```

Does POST work? Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20244577/21945) to a question that looks remarkably like yours, and see if you can get that to work.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had tried that. Now I get 100 into the id, but my Value is Null, where I expected it to be: "Hey"
Do you have an idea of that as well?

Comment: Try replacing "Hey" with some valid json. Maybe "{\"value\":\"Hey\"}"