# How to post multiple parameters including arrays to web api

Tags: c#, jquery, api

I have a asp.net web api controller method need the following parameters:

```
  public string Post(int id, List<Guid> guidIds)
```

I know for the regular multiple parameters passing, I can use

```
 localhost/api/controller/?parameters1=xxx&parameters2=yyy
```

I'm not sure if it still use thie format to pass multiple parameters including an array.
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602043/rest-api-best-practice-how-to-accept-as-input-a-list-of-parameter-values

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33345873/65775