# WebApi Put, how pass the params?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have created a webApi that automatically created som methods for me.
That Put-Method got created like this:

```
 // PUT: api/Actor/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutActor(int id, Actor actor)
    {
        //Code that updates the actor
    }
```

But How can i call this method?
Im thinking that it must start with:

```
HttpResponseMessage response =  client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/Actors/")  <-How can i add the two params?
```

According to some posts you cant do it without workarounds:

[WebAPI Multiple Put/Post parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407458/webapi-multiple-put-post-parameters)

But it seems strange considering that the method got created to me automatically. Should be a standard way to do it no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the `id`  in the route, whereas the Actor in the payload using the [`following overload`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944523(v=vs.118).aspx) which takes as second argument an object:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/Actors/123", new 
{
    actor = new Actor
    {
        Name = "John Smith",
        Age = 30,
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I now understand how I can pass my actor. But I do not understand how I Can pass the Id in the route. Does this mean that I should make changes in the webapiconfig?

Comment: Normally the default route setup includes the `id` token as part of the route. So all you have to do is pass it in there as shown in my answer: `"api/Actors/123"` where `123` is your id.