# MVC Web API, Error: Can't bind multiple parameters

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I get error when passing the parameters,

> "Can't bind multiple parameters"

**here is my code**

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GenerateToken([FromBody]string userName, [FromBody]string password)
{
    //...
}
```

**Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: 'http://localhost:14980/api/token/GenerateToken',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { userName: "userName",password:"password" },

    success: function (response) {
    },

    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        console.log(jqXhr.responseText);
        alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown + ": " + jqXhr.responseText + "  " + jqXhr.status);
    },
    complete: function (jqXhr) {

    },
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebAPI Multiple Put/Post parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407458/webapi-multiple-put-post-parameters)

Comment: Dear Paul.
I just checked the mention question this is not duplicate because that question is different than my current question. Thank you

Comment: Are you using Web API 1 or 2?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Reference: [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API - Using [FromBody]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody)

> **At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body. So
>   this will not work**:
>
> ```
> // Caution: Will not work!    
> public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string name) { ... }
> ```
>
> The reason for this rule is that the request body might be stored in a
>   non-buffered stream that can only be read once.

***emphasis mine***

That being said. You need create a model to store the expected aggregated data.

```
public class AuthModel {
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

and then update action to expect that model in the body

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GenerateToken([FromBody] AuthModel model) {
    string userName = model.userName;
    string password = model.password;
    //...
}
```

making sure to send the payload properly

```
var model = { userName: "userName", password: "password" };
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: 'http://localhost:14980/api/token/GenerateToken',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    success: function (response) {
    },

    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        console.log(jqXhr.responseText);
        alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown + ": " + jqXhr.responseText + "  " + jqXhr.status);
    },
    complete: function (jqXhr) {

    },
})
```