# POST data is null with ASP.NET API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to migrate to an ASP.NET 6 API controller and my POST data from my JS function is showing as null.

I have the following json request:

```
// searchTerms is an array with 2 properties, Value and Type
$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        searchTerms
    })
```

if I POST this to an ASP.NET 6 MVC controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(List<SearchTerm> searchTerms)
```

Then my searchTerms list is properly populated.

If I POST to an API Controller

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/search")]
public IHttpActionResult Search([FromBody] List<SearchTerm> searchTerms)
```

Then searchTerms is null.

I have tried to change the contentType, dataType, remove the stringify function to no avail.

I have tried to changed the signature to

```
public IHttpActionResult Search([FromBody] dynamic value)
```

And see the following, so obviously I'm not binding properly?

[image]

Here is my SearchTerm model:

```
public class SearchTerm
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your SearchTerm model?

Comment: I think you're passing a model which has a list of `SearchTerm`s in it instead of passing a list directly. But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    searchTerms
})
```

Change your `$.ajax` call to use just:

```
data: JSON.stringify(searchTerms)
```

You are sending JSON that looks something like:

```
{
    "seachTerms": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

With the change I suggested, this would just be a simple JSON array, which should work in your example.

Comment: Quick question, how do I now add other paramaters? (ie, an integer)

Comment: Have a look at @Nkosi's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44599682/2630078 and be sure to upvote his answer if it helps.