# Can't bind multiple parameters to the request's content

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have two class and basically I am trying to call two separate models with two store procedures to insert data in both table. I wrote my controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Adddata([FromBody]IList<Details> details,[FromBody] Request request)
{
    var changerequestResponse = db.sp_AddChangerequests(request.EmpID, request.CreatedDate, request.Status).SingleOrDefault();
    GenericResponse objResponse = null;
    foreach (Details detail in detailss)
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.sp_AddChangerequestDetails(detailss.CRID, detailss.Category, detailss.Info, detailss.Col, detailss.Reason).SingleOrDefault(), Formatting.Indented, settings);
        objResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GenericResponse>(data);

    }
    return Ok(objResponse);

}
```

and my controller js file like this:

```
$scope.SubmitrequestForm = function(){            
    console.log($scope.changereqcol);
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: WebApiUrl + 'Adddata',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: JSON.stringify($scope.changereqcol)
    }
    console.log()
    $http(req).then(function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
    }, function (err, status) {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```

when I am trying to submit the data I am getting above error. Can you please tell me  what I am missing

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, there can be at most one parameter per action decorated with `[FromBody]`. Therefore, I suggest you to merge your models in one request;

Comment: Can't bind multiple parameters to the request content.

Comment: I tried with that already but getting compile time error.. Maybe I am missing something as I am very new in this so if you could give me any example just for better understanding

Comment: Please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599041/mvc-web-api-error-cant-bind-multiple-parameters

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: No.. I think I am missing something.. I am very new in this so not getting exactly what I need to do.. Can you please correct  my code.

Comment: Can you show us your complete `Controller` and `View` code ?

Comment: Sorry i can't write whole code here because of some restrictions and whole controller has so many lines of code which is not possible to mention here.. But i gave the respective post method and api call code above. Is it ok for you??

Comment: What is the Model type for  `$scope.changereqcol data?` Also remove the extra `[FromBody]`: `public IHttpActionResult Adddata([FromBody]IList<Details> details,Request request)`

Comment: IList<Details> details

Comment: Did you try my above comment ?

Comment: yes removed the extra [FromBody]

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1) source:

> Don't apply [FromBody] to more than one parameter per action method. Once the request stream is read by an input formatter, it's no longer available to be read again for binding other [FromBody] parameters.

Comment: This is the actual answer. You can't bind FromBody more than once. Make FromBody a class that contains all the data you need

Answer (score 0):

Please Take look at jquery POST Method in keys : value set your data

```js
function verifyRiderAppID() {

 $.post("/url ", {
   Parms: value
  },
  function (data, status) {
   if (status === 'success') {

   } else {
    //else logic
   }
  });
}
```