# ASP.net controller for delete - "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a stored proc in SQL called "person_connections_delete". I have written a controller to call the stored proc however, this error message keeps coming up

*"message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:3024/api/personconnections/delete'.",
    "messageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'PersonConnections' that matches the request."*

Here is the stored proc. I'm passing three parameters into the stored proc for the delete.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[person_connections_delete]
    @PersonId INT,
    @FriendId INT,
    @Status INT
AS
    /*
        DECLARE
            @_personId INT = 1,
            @_friendId INT = 200,
            @_status INT = 1
        EXEC person_connections_delete
            @_personId,
            @_friendId,
            @_status
    */
BEGIN
    DELETE
        person_connections
    WHERE
        PersonId = @PersonId and FriendId = @FriendId
    IF (@Status = 1)
    DELETE
        person_connections
    WHERE
        PersonId = @FriendId and FriendId = @PersonId
END
```

The service and controller. in C#:

```
public void Delete(int personId, int friendId, int status)
        {
            _dataProvider.ExecuteNonQuery(
                "person_connections_delete",
                inputParamMapper: delegate (SqlParameterCollection paramCol)
                {
                    paramCol.AddWithValue("@PersonId", personId);
                    paramCol.AddWithValue("@FriendId", friendId);
                    paramCol.AddWithValue("@Status", status);
                }
            );
        }

[AllowAnonymous]
    [RoutePrefix("api/personconnections")]
    public class PersonConnectionsController : ApiController
    {
        private IPersonConnectionsService _personConnectionsService;

[HttpDelete]
        [Route("delete")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int personId, int friendId, int status)
        {
            try {
                if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                    ItemResponse<PersonConnectionsDeleteDomain> resp = new ItemResponse<PersonConnectionsDeleteDomain>();
                    _personConnectionsService.Delete(personId, friendId, status);
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, resp);
                } else {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotModified, ModelState);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
            }
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest taking a look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger to see how your route is being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

[See *Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api). WebAPI can't bind multiple parameters from body natively.

> When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header
>   to select a formatter. In this example, the content type is
>   "application/json" and the request body is a raw JSON string (not a
>   JSON object).
>
> At most one parameter is allowed to read from the
>   message body. So this will not work:
>
> ```
> // Caution: Will not work!    
> public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string name) { ... }
> ```
>
> The reason for this rule is that the request body might be stored in a
>   non-buffered stream that can only be read once.

There are other SO questions that ask how to achieve this, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407458/webapi-multiple-put-post-parameters). But unless you have a real reason to do so, I think you are better off using [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) or query string parameters.

Comment: You mentioned that WebAPI can't bind multiple POST parameters, but I'm assuming DELETE is the same?

Comment: Sorry, my bad I did not notice it was a delete method. But yes, it should be the same as a post method. The documentation does not say anything about binding from body limitations not applying to delete method or applying only to post methods. I have edited my answer.