# c# creating HTTP POST web request

Tags: c#, post, service, swagger

hello guys i have swagger url http://somehost/swagger/index.html
end methods there as shown on image: 
[image]

I am trying to create HTTP POST web request refer to one of the post method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
namespace SwaggerConsoleAPP
{
    class Program
    {  
        static  void Main(string[] args)
        {
            postRequest("http://somehost/api/Referral/GetReferralsByPersonalIdNumber");
                Console.ReadKey();
        }

        async  static void postRequest (string url){
            IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queries = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1133221221","5642")

            };
            HttpContent q = new FormUrlEncodedContent(queries);
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage responce = await client.PostAsync(url,q))
                 {
                    using (HttpContent content = responce.Content)
                    {
                        string mycontent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        Console.WriteLine(mycontent);
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
}
    }
```

this is console application but console writes error:

> {"":["The input was not valid."]}

This is model of method
[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, key value pair is causing the problem.

The API is expecting `personalIDNumber` and `pharmacyID` as two separate parameters.

Simplest solution is to just create a class with these two properties:

```
public class InputFields
{
    public string personalIDNumber{get;set;}
    public string pharmacyId{get;set;}
}
```

This will work as long as your API has mode of this type as input parameter.

Please note that sending two parameters in HTTP body as post you may have to code additionally [as mentioned here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407458/webapi-multiple-put-post-parameters)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you I created class like your answer and it works, I retrieve data.

Comment: I created code based on answers on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request?rq=1