# The JSON value could not be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken. Path: $ | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 8

Tags: json.net

I have a ASP.Net Core WebApi with a update Action as follows:

```
   [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Campaigns(long id, JObject jobject)
    {

    }
```

The request and response when I hit this endpoint from postman are below:-

```
{
"Zone_Code": 1,
"State_Code": 24,
"City_Code": 25,
"Sales_Associate": null,
"Operation_Associate": null,
"Traveller": null,
"Target_Sector": 5,
"Campaign_DateTime": "2020-04-04T00:00:00",
"Format": 2,
"Campaign_Name": "Test",
"Data_Criteria": null,
"IsActive":"Y",
"Stage": "Initiation"
}


{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "|58a198b0-4ac4ca0838cdebce.",
"errors": {
    "$": [
        "The JSON value could not be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken. Path: $ | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 8."
    ]
}}
```

Comment: Why you use ``JObject`` like a parameter of the action?you can use a simple object

Comment: My handler code uses reflection to set properties' values

Comment: i don't see the handler in your question, i tried a simple test, with ``JObject`` gives me the same error, and with a *simple object* i'm calling the *Action*.

Answer (score 32):

You have an exception in your code, because you use default json serializer/deserializer in ASP.Net Core WebAPI - `System.Text.Json`.
You can find in [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to), that `System.Text.Json` doesn't support such deserialization.

You need to switch your default json serializer/deserializer to `Newtonsoft.Json`, do the following steps:

1. Install the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson) NuGet package.
2. In `ConfigureServices()` add a call to `AddNewtonsoftJson()`

```
serviceCollection.AddControllers()
.AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

For more information about `System.Text.Json` you can find in [Microsoft blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/)

Comment: This helped me perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Does this still work? When I run command VS isn't able to find the package to install it...

Comment: Try command `dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson --version 6.0.9`, but it is for .net 6.0. If you use the previous version, install another version.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the root issue is .net core 3 uses System.Text.Json. I believe you want to use System.Text.Json.JsonElement. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to