# C# received [HTTPPOST] request

Tags: c#

for C# WebApi, I used this function to deal with the *POST* request from my front end, code as below **Method1**:

```
[HttpPost]
public object GetPostItem(string Name, string email, int Code)
{
  //perform something here
}
```

but it seems like it didn't work, unless I try for 
**Method2**

```
[HttpPost]
public object GetPostItem(info Info)
{
  //This is how I get them from *Info*
  info.Name
  info.email
  info.Code
  //perform something here
}
```

Is there any way for letting function *POST* to received object separately or the only way to deal with *POST* is **Method2**
?

Comment: How does the form look like with which you post?

Comment: @GSerg It is something like this `{Name= myName, email= a@a.com, Code=0}`
FYI my frontend is using **React**

Comment: I think your question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407458/webapi-multiple-put-post-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) And body is default source in post. You can use parameters by `FromUri` Attribute.

Comment: i see:
`When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header to select a formatter. In this example, the content type is "application/json" and the request body is a raw JSON string (not a JSON object).

At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body. So this will not work`
I think this answer my question

Comment: So may I conclude that the above **Method1** from question is actually cannot worked?

Comment: If you want to use body, and default, build in WebService request handling, yes.

Comment: hmm let's see, so general conclusion, only params (like **HttpGet**) will be using **Method1** while **HttpPost** which pass though body will be using **Method2**

Comment: You can use Method2 with [FromUri], but params must be in ulr, not in body. Get not have body, so default source is FromUri, but in post you must add attribute to read from uri.

Comment: yup that make clear for me, appreciated your answer and time, Leszek  ;D