# How to get request body data from System.Mvc.Web.ActionExecutingContext in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httprequest

Here is my method It will take only one parameter . But I want user whaterver add in request body I need to save in logging.

```
[HttpPost]
[LogAPIUser]
public async Task<JsonResult> GameDetail(long game)
```

Here is my Postman request [image]

In ActionExecutingContext I have got only one action parameter

[image]

How can I get all body request data?
If anyone have idea please let me know

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api states that:

At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body.

The reason for this rule is that the request body might be stored in a non-buffered stream that can only be read once.

You can try to look at this question:
[WebAPI Multiple Put/Post parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407458/webapi-multiple-put-post-parameters)

- basically, you read the whole body, and get your elements out of it.

something in the effect of

```
[HttpPost]
public string MyMethod([FromBody]JObject data)
{
    long game = data["game"].ToObject<Long>();
    long rer = data["rer"].ToObject<Long>();
}
```

(did not try code, might be buggy)

Comment: Michael thanks for replying,

I my case it's not working

And I have resolved the issue now.

Comment: how did you resolve it?

Comment: Hi Michael,

I have using that 
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

Comment: ok, that is a solution, and i dont know your exact scenario. that could either work, or if its ever a non-buffered stream, then you will crash here, setting that property