# How to deal with arbitrary JSON in ASP.NET WebAPI?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I need to create two endpoints with WebAPI. One will accept arbitrary JSON and an integer key, the other will return said JSON.

```
    [Route("UpdateData")]
    public async Task UpdateData(int dataKey, [HttpPost] XXX data)
    {

    }

    [Route("GetData")]
    public async Task<???> GetData(int dataKey)
    {

    }
```

I know how to do the database storage, I just need to know what the public API should look like.

Comment: Would DynamicJsonObject be right?

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573384/how-to-post-arbitrary-json-object-to-webapi

Comment: That one's all over the map with no hint as to which is preferable or why.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Route("UpdateData")]
public async Task UpdateData(int dataKey, [FromBody] JObject data)
{

}

[Route("GetData")]
public async Task<JObject> GetData(int dataKey)
{

}
```